# Accept either int or tuple of ints as a python function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def port_status(self, port=(1, 2)):
    for i in port:
        print_status(i)
```

But I'd like the user to be able to also call the function with a single port number like so:

```
port_status(port=2)
```

In this specific case, it would end up as the following:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Is there some python magic I could use here?

Comment: "Magic"? No. Just check the type of the argument passed in. (Or catch the exception and deal with it appropriately.)

Comment: Do you really need that default tuple?

Comment: @StefanPochmann well actually I'm not sure. I just want to show status of every ports if the user doesn't specify the port number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the type of `port`.

```
def port_status(self, port=(1, 2)):
    if isinstance(port, int):
        port = (port,)
    for i in port:
        print_status(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic, but in general you live with duck typing by trying to figure out if the input behaves in your expected way.  This can be coupled with trying to preprocess them first in the way you want.

For example, you can modify your function to look like:

```
def port_status(self, port)
    ports = validate_ports(port)
    for p in ports:
        # use p as individual port
```

where, in the function `validate_ports` you can use a `try` block to tentatively figure out (and possibly bridge) the desired behavior and the actual one, for a very crude example:

```
def validate_ports(port):
    try:
        portiter = iter(port)
    except TypeError:
        return [port]
    return list(portiter)
```

This function always returns a list, so in the case when the input is a valid list of `int`s or an `int`, nothing breaks.  But despite the name, the individual members can still behave badly, and you'll need to handle exceptions in the rest of the code.

In general, [using `isinstance` can be unwieldy](http://canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/) with Python's duck typing, and concepts like "a sequence of `int`s" isn't really enforceable in Python. It's your choice to mix some [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) with [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) or go purist, and the choice is quite subjective, which might as well be described as "magic".

Answer (score -1):

Your for i in port requires port to be a iterable object. So you could just pass port_status port=(2), and it would work.